# QUrlQuery не видит параметры

Tags: qt, сокет, get, tcp

QUrlQuery не видит GET параметры url ссылки, если она получена из сокета. По непонятным мне причинам раз от разу просто не работает

```
tempClientSocket = tcpServer->nextPendingConnection();
...
QString tmp=tempClientSocket->readAll();
....
QUrlQuery(tmp.split(" ").at(1));
qDebug() << query.queryItemValue("email");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решить проблему удалось, написав свою функцию для разбора параметров GET запроса

```
QMap<QString,QString> ParseUrlParameters(QString &url)
{
    //Заранее создаем коллекцию для возвращаемого значения
    QMap<QString,QString> ret;

    //Параметров нет. Возвращаем пустую коллекцию
    if(url.indexOf('?')==-1)
    {
        return ret;
    }

    //Обрезаем из url все до вопроса
    QString tmp = url.right(url.length()-url.indexOf('?')-1);

    //Разбиваем в коллекцию параметров через разделитель &
    QStringList paramlist = tmp.split('&');

    //Ввожу параметры в коллекцию
    for(int i=0;i<paramlist.count();i++)
    {
        QStringList paramarg = paramlist.at(i).split('=');
        ret.insert(paramarg.at(0),paramarg.at(1));
    }

    //Вывожу в консоль полученные параметры
    QMapIterator<QString, QString> i(ret);
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        i.next();
        qDebug() << i.key() << ":" << i.value() << endl;
    }

    return ret;
}
```